# Count values for a specified month

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Column A has date values (dd/mm/yyyy) and column B contains OK for some dates and is blank for others:

```
      A         B
1 01/12/2015    Ok
2 01/12/2015    Ok
3 01/11/2015    
4 01/12/2015    Ok
5 01/11/2015    
6 01/01/2015    OK
7 01/12/2015
```

I am trying to count OK's if the associated date falls within a month that is specified in the mmm format (e.g., Dec).

In this example, the result for Dec is 3 (three rows with a date that falls in December and a value of OK.  The result for Nov is 0 because there are no November dates with a value of OK.

I tried some of the answers given to related questions on Super User but they did not work on my spreadsheet.  For example:

=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT($A$1:$A$7,"Mmmm")="Dec")*($B$1:$B$7="OK")*$B$1:$B$7)

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Hi Fixer1234 thanks for replying. I need a formula that would calculate the total of "OK" which is in cell B when the month is Dec

Comment: Fixer1234 &jcerbmu - I've tried the answers here but some how still the same, I even tried to change the format of the date to number format still same, how to send the actual template to you..I can't copy the image here ....

Comment: If you have any file or image sharing service, just post a link here to a screenshot and someone will add it for you.  I tested the formulas in LibreOffice Calc and they worked.  I'll retest in Excel when I get back to Windows (had to test with mm/dd/yyyy format for the data because I'm in the US).  Can you describe exactly what you're trying and the results you get?  Did you try to copy and paste the formulas in the answers?  BTW, you need to "address" comments with @username or nobody will be aware of your posting.

Comment: @fixer1234 thanks for letting me know how to address comment properly.

Comment: @fixer1234 the link and explanation is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16VSt_LUnGEIdr57d67TbO-rsFijIZJR7LAoH_V-ipyM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see a bunch of dates in a different format from your question and nothing else that resembles your question.  That looks like a different problem from what you have described here.  There are no formulas, nothing that reflects the information in the answers, and nothing that sheds light on what you find doesn't work.

Comment: @fixer1234 actually the template I attached is the original one. Anyway what I was asking in the earlier question is to check a set of dates in one cell and sum the total which have the value ok but my actual template I need to be able to count Ok , Not Ok and blank due to my aim is to get a percentage. apologize if not mentioned clearly what I need.

Comment: It looks like you had a question, you asked a different question, you received answers to the question you asked, and now you're saying the answers don't work for your original question, which you didn't ask.  Super User doesn't work that way.  Each question becomes part of a knowledgebase and the answers solve that question.  If you have another question, ask another question.  However, first we need to put this one to bed, on its own.

Comment: @fixer1234 ok noted. I have accepted the answers for the question raised earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the best that you can get, and I will explain why:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A7,">=01/12/2015",A1:A7,"<=31/12/2015",B1:B7,"=Ok")
```

The dates on Excel are a little tricky. Excel sees them as numbers, for example:

`01/11/2015` is `42309`

`01/12/2015` is `42339`

Do you see the difference of 30 among them?

When a cell shows *DEC* you are seeing a **visual format** of the number 42339 inside the cell.

The main problem of your requirement is that you want as *criteria* the 3-letter name of the month (JAN, FEB, MAR, APR... etc.), but Excel formulas use the number, not the visual format.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an incorrect date format and syntax errors in your formula.  It will work if you clean it up to look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT($A$1:$A$7,"mmm")="Dec"),($B$1:$B$7="OK"))
```

You can do something similar if you can use the month number instead of the abbreviation.  The MONTH function will convert the date into the month number, so the formula would look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$7)=12),($B$1:$B$7="OK"))
```